# Как сделать так чтобы yield return возвращал "Да", если b равно true, "Нет" если b равен false, и прекращал отдавать элементы, если b равен null

Tags: c#

Дан следующий код:

```
class Program
    {
        static bool? b = true;

        static void Main()
        {
          //Проверочный код
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> IsTrue()
        {

        }
    }
```

Как сделать так чтобы возвращал  "Да", если b равен true, "Нет" если b равен false, и прекращал отдавать элементы, если b равен null.
Пробовал реализовать таким способом:

```
static IEnumerable<string> IsTrue()
    {
        if(b == true) { yield return "Да"; }
        if (b == false) { yield return "Нет"; }
        yield break;

    }
```

Но я так понимаю таким образом не будет возвращаться да или нет в зависимости от булевого значения, так как итератор будет вначале возвращать "Да" как реализовать метод так, чтобы он возвращал мне значение в соответствии с задачей.

Comment: " в соответствии с задачей" --- какой задачей?  сейчас задача у тебя "чтобы возвращал "Да", если b равен true, "Нет" если b равен false" ..... что вполне и происходит.

Comment: `IEnumerable` при чем тут, если у вас возвращается из метода только одно значение?

Comment: Этот код работает? Не работает? В чем проблема?

Comment: 1. Не могу понять что написать в Main() для проверки. 
2. Не могу заставить этот класс через метод yield return возвращать "Да" "Нет" в зависимости от true false и прекращал работать если null .
Задача абстрактная, на практику метод yield return, это все условия которые в ней есть, но у меня что-то вообще не получается понять как это решить

Comment: `foreach (string text in IsTrue()) Console.WriteLine(text);` Кстати, `yield break` можно убрать, так как дальше кода нет.

Comment: «Чтобы `yield return` возвращал `"Да"`, если `b` равен `true`»: равен `true`в момент перечисления или в момент получения объекта `IEnumerable<string>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static IEnumerable<string> IsTrue()
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            if(b == true) 
            {
                yield return "Да";
            }
            else if (b == false)
            {
                yield return "Нет";
            }
            else if(b == null)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Надо было сделать yield return с циклом while и тогда это считалось правильным ответом